# One of two text boxes are not updated with binding

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have two search text boxes, `Above` and `Below`, that I have to set restrains on. 
The number in `Below` can't be higher than the number in `Above` and the number in `Above` can't be lower than the one in `Below`.

If one number is not right, it will should be set equal to the other number.

The problem is that `Above` doesn't get updated, 
while `Bottom` does (even though the properties are set in the same way).

**xaml**:

```
<common:SearchTextBox Grid.Column="1" 
    VerticalAlignment="Center"
    Label="Enter value in feet"
    common:AllowableTextInput.IsIgnoreWhiteSpace="True"
    common:AllowableTextInput.IsMatch="^[0-9]{0,5}$"
    Text="{Binding Path=AboveAircraft, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,
      Converter={StaticResource AboveAircraftConveter}, ConverterParameter=4000}"/>
<Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" 
    Style="{StaticResource FormLabelStyle}"
    Content="Below Aircraft (ft):"/>
<common:SearchTextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" 
    VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
    common:AllowableTextInput.IsIgnoreWhiteSpace="True"
    common:AllowableTextInput.IsMatch="^[0-9]{0,5}$"
    Text="{Binding Path=BelowAircraft, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,
      Converter={StaticResource BelowAircraftConveter}, ConverterParameter=2000}"
    Label="Enter value in feet" />
```

**C#**:

```
public int AboveAircraft
{
    get { return _above; }
    set
    {   
        if (SetProperty(ref _above, value, "AboveAircraft") && _updateModel)
        {
            if (Model.AltitudeBand == null)
            {
                Model.AltitudeBand = new AltitudeBand();
            }

            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {

                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("AboveAircraft"));
                if (_above < _below)
                {
                     _below = AboveAircraft;
                }
            }

            Model.AltitudeBand.Above = new AltitudeBandLimit() { Unit = AltitudeUnit.Foot, Value = _above };
        }
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Below the route of flight in ft
/// </summary>
public int BelowAircraft
{
    get { return _below; }
    set
    {
       if (SetProperty(ref _below, value, "BelowAircraft") && _updateModel)
       {
            if (Model.AltitudeBand == null)
            {
                Model.AltitudeBand = new AltitudeBand();
            }

            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                _below = value;
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("BelowAircraft"));
                if (_below > _above)
                {
                    AboveAircraft = _below;
                }
            }
           Model.AltitudeBand.Below = new AltitudeBandLimit() { Unit = AltitudeUnit.Foot, Value = _below };
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What values are you testing? What do `AboveAircraftConveter` and `BelowAircraftConveter` do? What effect do the `ConverterParameter` values have?

Comment: Here is the converters:

Comment: AboveAircraftConveter and BelowAircraftConveter convert int to string. The ConverterParameter sets the default value on the screen. I tested different value from 1000 to 9000.

Comment: @EdChapel: It's not important what they do. The issue is, that if `AboveAircraft` is set, it changes the `_below` value, which is a private variable and not the property. This causes the UI not being notified when `BelowAircraft` changes, hence the UI won't update the value. See my answer below

Comment: @Tseng You are right. I was looking for any unexplained behavior. Your answer shows you found the inconsistency I missed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using  `_below = AboveAircraft;` in your `AboveAircraft`
 setter method but you are binding `BelowAircraft`.

Either change `_below = AboveAircraft;` to `BelowAircraft = AboveAircraft;` or send notification for `BelowAircraft` too, i.e.

```
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {

                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("AboveAircraft"));
                if (_above < _below)
                {
                     _below = AboveAircraft;
                     PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("BelowAircraft"));
                }
            }
```

When you change a property that changes another binded property, you have to send notification for **both** Properties, not only one.

Of course you have to apply the same changes to the `BelowAircraft` setter too.

**Edit**:
Just for clarification: Which one of the both methods depends if setting the property would cause a circular event triggering or not. If it would cause a circular event (i.e. endless triggering) then you only have to send a second notification like the code above.

**Edit 2**:
In reply to the comment, your XAML Binding is set to `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged`. This means, your `setter` will be called with each character you type in.

When you enter "4000" the first character in the "Above" field will be 4 and this causes the below value to 4. Instead you want to update the Text field only when the user has completed his input.

According to the MSDN documentation for "[UpdateSourceTrigger Enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.updatesourcetrigger.aspx)" there are 4 values. For text field you may want to use `UpdateSourceTrigger=Default` or `UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus`. Then the setter will only be called when the user is finished with his input instead of calling the setter on each character typed in the text field.

Comment: The below one still works but whenever a number is entered in Above, it sets the first digit in the Below box. For example, the default above number is 4000 and below number is 2000. If I change the above number to 1000 then the below number changed to 1. We want it to change to 1000 to match the above number.

Comment: The event got fired for the above number as soon as the first digit is entered. It then sent the digit to the below number.

Comment: Maybe you should update your question then. The problem in the question is not identical to what you post in the comment. Also according to your commented issue, I'll update my answer in short

Comment: Yes, the two textboxes should do the exactly the same thing. But one of them is doing right (below) but the other one (Above) is not even though the code for both are the same. For example, the default number for Above is 4000 and Below is 2000 when I first launch the program. I can change the below number to 5000 then the above number changes to 5000 immediately. However, if I change the above number to 1500, now 1 is in the below box.

Comment: That's two issues. One of it is, that your posted `AboveAircraft` do not notify the UI. The other issue is, that from my "Edit 2", where each typed letter will cause the setter to update since you use `PropertyChanged` as trigger.

Comment: The code BelowAirCraft does the exactly the same thing. Why does AboveAircraft do not notify the UI? How do I make change for it?

Comment: Read my answer. In `AboveAircraft` there is an additional `PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("BelowAircraft"));` in my answer after `_below = AboveAircraft;`. This will notify the UI that `BelowAircraft` has been changed!!

Comment: And `_below = AboveAircraft;` and `AboveAircraft = _below;` in your setters is not the **exactly same code**. The first one sets a private variable. The second one sets a property which has UI notification code (the `PropertyChanged(..)`)!

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. I changed UpdateSourceTrigger=Default and it worked. I tried Lostfocus earlier and it didn't change. Maybe the UI notification was right earlier. Very helpful!!!